# Allowing login for multiple clients from one realm in KeyCloak

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I'm using React.js + keycloak to implement the SSO in my project and currently I'm using one client from one realm. I wonder that can we allow multiple clients login in one realm in key-cloaks from same login keycloak page?

To be more clear,
For example, I have one realm called testRealm and it has two clients called testClient1, testClient2 and lastly user t1 has role called tester in testClient1 and user t2 has role called viewer in testClient2. In key-cloak login page, I want to user get their corresponding roles from different clients after login in react.

**My current Keyclaok keycloakAuth instance**

```
const keycloakAuth = new Keycloak({
url: url,
realm: "testRealm",
clientId: "testClient1",
});
```

**My Ideal Keyclaok keycloakAuth instance**
I would like to support one more realm called testClient2. How can we achieve this in react?